# Directional buttons do not work in the "negative" direction

Tags: android, button, imageview

I am trying to make an image view move Up/Down/Left/Right using image buttons.  I am able to get the image to move right and down, however up and left do not work.

I have tried changing the +/- sign, the length of the increments to move the image, and also the if/else statements to determine whether or not to move the image.

```
 // Move ImageView Up
 case R.id.upBtn: {
     if (img.getY() > 0) {
        img.setY(img.getY() - 25);
    }
}

// Move ImageView Down
case R.id.downBtn: {
    if (img.getY() < 950) {
        img.setY(img.getY() + 25);
    }
}

// Move ImageView Left
case R.id.leftBtn: {
    if (img.getX() > 0) {
        img.setX(img.getX() - 25);
    }
}

// Move ImageView Right
case R.id.rightBtn: {
    if (img.getX() < 2000) {
        img.setX(img.getX() + 25);
    }
}
```

The image view is supposed to move in all directions but it won't go in the up or left directions.  I removed the if/else statements to see if they were the issue and they had no effect in regards to moving the image.  They just keep it from going off the screen.  It appears that I can not subtract from the getY() function but that does not make sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing `break` statements, so once a `case` is matched, the code of all following `case` statements will also execute.

Try :

```
// Move ImageView Up
case R.id.upBtn: {
     if (img.getY() > 0) {
        img.setY(img.getY() - 25);
    }
}
break;

// Move ImageView Down
case R.id.downBtn: {
    if (img.getY() < 950) {
        img.setY(img.getY() + 25);
    }
}
break;

// Move ImageView Left
case R.id.leftBtn: {
    if (img.getX() > 0) {
        img.setX(img.getX() - 25);
    }
}
break;

// Move ImageView Right
case R.id.rightBtn: {
    if (img.getX() < 2000) {
        img.setX(img.getX() + 25);
    }
}
break;

default :
```